# Replace for loop with LINQ

Tags: linq

Is there is a LINQ expression equivalent to below code?

```
int noOfColumns = 10;
for (int i = 2; i <= noOfColumns+1; i++)
{                    
    sql.AppendFormat(" [{0}{1}] [varchar]({2}),", "commodity", columnLength);
}
```

Comment: Flippant answer: this code doesn't compile. More serious answer? Probably not one that's as performant.

Comment: I am just trying to generate dynamic sql to create a table from code behind. The number of columns will be changing at runtime (could be 1000 some times). Being novice to LINQ i thought it may add value. Thanks all for your time

Comment: @Kiran: Are you having any issue with the current code? Why you want to do it in `linq`?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: No, the current code works fine. But i thought the LINQ might be better performant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(2, noOfColumns+1)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(i => 
     sql.AppendFormat(" [{0}{1}] [varchar]({2}),", "commodity" columnLength));
```

But I don't think it looks better :-).

Comment: I've removed my `-1` because I'm _pretty_ sure you're joking :)

Comment: It is just an answer for the question :-) I hope it will tell author that it's not necessary to use LINQ everywhere

Comment: @Nagg: I am not sure how this part doesn't comes up with any errors `"commodity" columnLength`

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the (compiling) Linq replacement would be:

```
IEnumerable<string> cols = Enumerable.Range(2, noOfColumns +1)
    .Select(i => string.Format(" [{0}] [varchar]({1})", "commodity", columnLength));
string sql = string.Join(",", cols);
```

But i must admit that i have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: TIL that `String.Join` uses a `StringBuilder` behind the scenes.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, you're right. Removed the "without `StringBuilder`".

Comment: That wasn't a criticism, I'd just never thought about it and thought `Join` (at least the array version) would allocate space for the whole thing and then fill it.

Comment: @Rawling: I've noticed it recently. But the [`string.Join(string[])` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/57a79xd0.aspx) uses a very efficient copy  method `memcpyimpl` instead of a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter:I am just trying to generate dynamic sql to create a table from code behind. The number of columns will be changing at runtime (could be 1000 some times). Being novice to LINQ i thought it may add value. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of `Enumerable.Range` are `start` and `count`. This means that it does not directly replace for loops.

`for(var i = 5; i < 8; ++i)` will produce the numbers from 5 to 7.

`Enumerable.Range(5, 8)` will produce the numbers from 5 to 12 (5+8-1).

To get the desired effect, `Enumerable.Range(start, end - start)` would need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Enumerable.Range(2, noOfColumns).ToList().ForEach(r => { sql.AppendFormat(" [{0}{1}] [varchar]({2}),", "commodity" columnLength); });
```

Comment: You're right, taking off the `+1` fixes a range error, doesn't it? Please accept my apologies. My downvote's locked in, but if you edit your answer (you could put some linebreaks in!) then I can remove it.

Comment: @Swani: Seems this doesn't compile !!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, The question itself not compile ('[{0}{1}] [varchar]({2}),", "commodity" columnLength); '), if you ignore that part.. rest is complied code :).

Comment: @Swani: So it mean it is fare to put something which not work as an answer?